# How to know under multiplication modulo operation the set is closed or not

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

{1,4,7,13}multiplication mod 15 is closed?                                    What is the meaning of {1,4 ,7,13}*15 I think the inverse of 4 is how many times we multiply 4  into  4 and devide by 15 such that remainder is 1.is this correct? But how the set is closed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Closed" in this context means that it is closed under the operation of multiplication mod $15$. So for any $a,b \in \{1,4,7,13\}$, $ab$ reduced mod $15$ (which is indeed the remainder of division by $15$) is in $\{1,4,7,13\}$. Now, lets refer to this operation of multiplication mod $15$ with the symbol $*$.

The inverse of $4$ would be the number $a \in \{1,4,7,13\}$ such that $4*a = 1$. The same goes for the other elements.

Comment: Hey Jonathan I can't understand clearly pls give me an example belongs to this set. According to your answer any ab belongs to {1,4,7,13} suppose 4 and7  such that 28 mod 15.  What reduces I can't understand pls explain me more

Comment: 4 times 7 = 28 which reduces to 13 mod 15.

Comment: Yes I got it  thanks a lot

Comment: Great, glad I could help. One thing to note, if you like the answer to a question, you should up-vote it (although it won't show up until you have at least 15 reputation) and if the answer was sufficient for you to answer your question, you should accept it.